# SignalR connection not working for all clients

Tags: asp.net, iis, signalr, iis-8.5

I'm having an issue where my SignalR messages are getting through to some clients but not others.

If I open the same application in Chrome Incognito, IE 11, Opera, Regular Chrome it will only connect to signalR in Opera and Regular Chrome.

An $mdToast dialog appears in the bottom left corner whenever a signalR message is recieved.

[image]

Even on the server itself I cannot get signalR to connect:

[image]

For good measure I also tried on a separate workstation on the same network and I'm getting no signalR connection at all:

[image]

I'm using SignalR v2.2.2:

[image]

The webserver I'm using is IIS 8.5.9600.16384:

[image]